# Bidirectional LSTM structure, data shape is incorrect

Tags: python, keras, lstm, bidirectional

I'm building the following three layer Bidirectional LSTM Keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features))))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', 'accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.3, epochs=2, batch_size=16, verbose=1, callbacks=[es, mc]
```

But, I keep getting errors (such as the following):

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_7 to have shape
> (30, 1) but got array with shape (15, 1)

These are the two data shapes that I tried using:

1. X.shape, y.shape = ((45176, 30, 1), (45176, 15, 1))
2. X.shape, y.shape = ((45176, 30, 1), (45176, 15, 1))

I'm trying to do a multi-step forecasting using: n_steps_in, n_steps_out = 30, 15
Which means, the model should provide 15 next time-step predictions (with an input of 30 time steps).

Comment: what are the values of n_steps_in, n_features ? Also, have you tried predicting a single value instead of sequences of 15?  Dense(1) is one output.

Comment: n_steps_in = 30, n_features = 1. I am able to predict multiple steps with a similar Dense(1) output in another LSTM structure; because I reshape data as: data.reshape((1, n_steps_in, n_features)) before using the model to predict multiple step (in my case it will provide 15 future time steps).